# Consulta para comparar el total de publicaciones aprobadas y rechazadas en cada año

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql

necesito que me apoyen con el siguiente problema, quiero comparar el total de publicaciones aprobadas y rechazadas en cada año para ello en mi base de datos sql server tengo las tablas Publicacion y estatus_publicacion y quiero que me traiga solamente las publicaciones con estatus aprobado y rechazado y mostrar por años en columnas con el total de publicaciones que tienen dicha condición. un ejemplo del resultado que quiero obtener es como el siguiente

ejemplo de resultado:

|Estatus    |Año2019 | año2020 |
|Aprobado   |32      | 46      |
|Rechazado  |23      | 52      |

*el ejemplo es el mismo que esta en la imagen de forma comentada.

En el año 2019 hay 32 publicaciones aprobadas y 23 rechazadas. En el año 2020 hay 46 publicaciones aprobadas y 52 rechazadas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La opción más fácil, es utilizar la función count con un case interno.

```
select [e].[nom_publicacion] as status
 , count(case
             when year([fecha_inicio_publicacion]) = 2019
             then 1
         end) as [Año2019]
 , count(case
             when year([fecha_inicio_publicacion]) = 2020
             then 1
         end) as [Año2020]
from 
    publicacion p
        inner join estatus_publicacion e on p.id_est_publicacion = e.id
Where fecha_inicio_publicacion >= '20190101' and fecha_inicio_publicacion < '20210101'
group by [e].[nom_publicacion];
```

-- Opción 2 es utilizar un pivot estático.

```
select pvt.nom_publicacion as status, pvt.[2019], pvt.[2020] from
(
    select e.nom_publicacion 
         , e.nom_publicacion as nom
         , Year(p.fecha_inicio_publicacion) as anual
        from publicacion p 
        inner join estatus_publicacion e on p.id_est_publicacion = e.id
 ) as source
pivot(count(nom) for anual in ([2019],[2020])) pvt
```

Salida

[image: Resultados]

[Pivot simple. Paso a paso](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/16/pivot-simple-como-hacer-y-entenderlo-paso-por-paso/)

Si quieres que evalúe las columnas en función de los años en los que tengas registros para que en los años siguientes se añada una columna, entonces ya hablaríamos de un pivot dinámico.

[Pivot dinámico. Paso a paso](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/14/pivot-dinamico-como-hacerlo-y-entenderlo/)

Continuación. Para traer Año Aprobado Rechazado.

```
select  pvt.* from
(
   select Year(p.fecha_inicio_publicacion) as a 
        , e.nom_publicacion as nom
        , Year(p.fecha_inicio_publicacion) as Año
       from publicacion p 
       inner join estatus_publicacion e on p.id_est_publicacion = e.id
) as source
pivot(count(a) for nom in ([Aprobado], [Rechazado])) pvt
```

Por supuesto que en la tabla derivada llamada source, puedes aplicar un where e.id in (1,2) para que te elimine, los valores que no correspondan con lo buscado.

Comment: Si me funciono de esa manera, ahora si yo quiero traer los datos de esta manera, AÑO | APROBADO | RECHAZADO. Asi que cada año me traiga su cantidad correspondiente, como podría hacerlo, nose si me explique bien, agradeceria mucho su ayuda

Comment: He aplicado un añadido para realizar un pivot sobre Año | Aprobado | Rechazado

Answer (score 1):

```
select YEAR(p.fecha_inicio_publicacion) as Año,
count(case when year([fecha_inicio_publicacion]) = 2019 and (p.id_est_publicacion) = 1 then 1 end) as Aprobados,
count(case when year([fecha_inicio_publicacion]) = 2019 and (p.id_est_publicacion) = 2 then 1 end) as Rechazados,
count(case when year([fecha_inicio_publicacion]) = 2020 and (p.id_est_publicacion) = 1 then 1 end) as Aprobados,
count(case when year([fecha_inicio_publicacion]) = 2020 and (p.id_est_publicacion) = 2 then 1 end) as Rechazados
from Publicacion p
group by YEAR(p.fecha_inicio_publicacion)
```

De esta manera hago nomas que me lo muestre, solo quiero una columna Año,aprobado y rechazado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]